# Why does my Perl calculator always return 0?

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement, do-while

Hello I new to Perl and I learning the basics and the idea is write a calculator that can run, and perform the basic operations like multiplication, addition, ... Using as well RegEx.

Now the problem is that I'm getting `0` no matter what and I was wondering if any one can check the code and maybe tell me if I did something wrong also I will like to ask about `chomp` is it better than `STDIN`?

My Perl code is this:

```
sub only_number
{
        ($num) = @_;

        do{
                print "Type a Number: ";
                $num = <STDIN>;
                if($num =~ /\D+.*\n$/){
                        print "Thats is not a number. >:[ \n";
                }
        } until($num = $num + 0);
};
&only_number($num1);

do{
        print "What do you want to do? ";
        $operator = <STDIN>;
        if($operator !~ /\/|\*|\-|\+/){
                print "Thats not a valid character (-_-;).\n"
        }
} until ($operator =~ /\/|\*|\-|\+/);

&only_number($num2);

if($operator eq "*\n"){
        $result = $num1*$num2;
}
elsif($operator eq "/\n"){
        $result = $num1/$num2;
}
elsif($operator eq "+\n"){
        $result = $num1+$num2;
}
elsif($operator eq "-\n"){
        $result = $num1-$num2;
}
print "your answer is $result\n";

exit;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think @Sinan Ünür meant `m{[\Q*/+-\E]}`, though `m{[*/+-]}` would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function  only_number did not return value nor did it change its argument actually. You program should work this way.

```
sub only_number
{
    my $num;
    while(1) {
            print "Type a Number: ";
            chomp($num = <STDIN>);
            if($num !~ /^\d+$/){
                    print "Thats is not a number. >:[ \n";
                    next;

            }
            return $num;
    }
};

my $num1 = only_number();

my $operator;
while(1) {
    print "What do you want to do? ";
    chomp($operator = <STDIN>);
    if($operator !~ /\/|\*|\-|\+/){
            print "Thats not a valid character (-_-;).\n"
            next;
    }
    last;
 }

 my $num2 = only_number();

 if($operator eq "*"){
    $result = $num1*$num2;
 }
 elsif($operator eq "/"){
    $result = $num1/$num2;
 }
 elsif($operator eq "+"){
    $result = $num1+$num2;
 }
 elsif($operator eq "-"){
    $result = $num1-$num2;
 }
 print "your answer is $result\n";

exit;
```

Comment: why did you add my in front of all the variables?

Comment: @TermMiator: you are really "new to pearl"! `my` is used to declare a new variable in the local scope.

Comment: To make them local.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes I'm, I just start to learn it last night

Comment: Don't forget to always add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top of every file which in your case will give you some errors to fix. `my` declares a locally scoped variable http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html

Comment: Thanks that use warnings show me all the errors on the file!

Comment: @TermMiator, fyi, `do BLOCK until EXPR` isn't a "real loop", so `next`, `last`, and `redo` can't be used to control its flow. As such, some people (myself included) avoid it. That's probably why Anton converted them into `while` loops.

Comment: @TermMiator You might want to search for better (more up-to-date) learning materials. The `&only_number();` subroutine call (with an ampersand) is Perl 4 style -- it was used over 20 years ago. It wasn't good style in 2000, it definitely isn't good style in 2016. Perl 5 style is `only_number();`

Comment: (I mean, it's not about style alone. The ampersand was required in Perl 4; Perl 5 (1994) made it optional and discouraged its use. A guide that uses the ampersand for subroutine calls is probably ancient or low in quality and should be avoided.)